# Can I save the Google username and password so that it doesn't show the authentication screen

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am building an app that edits a document in my app with Google Docs.
How can I save the username and password of the user so that the user doesn't have to type in his username and password each time he clicks on the edit option.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Can you make the documents public?